# Svg вырезание в фотографии

Tags: svg, mask

я хочу сделать еффект глюка но для этого мне нужно ВНУТРИ фото вырезать фигуру. То есть, не обрезать а вырезать в фото на svg помогите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы ***прорезать*** фигурное отверстие в изображении, используется маска SVG.
Если фигурам (**path**), входящим в маску задать цвет `fill="black"`то по форме этих фигур будет прорезано отверстие до более нижнего слоя или до backgrond`a. Подробнее о масках - [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1862)

В маске используется `<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />`
Для того, чтобы была видна остальная, не вырезанная часть изображения.

```html
<style>
 .container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 20 1200 800 ">
<defs>
 <mask id="mask" > 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <g fill="black" transform="translate(300 100) scale(2)" >
   <path   d="M89 31.3c-1.5-.1-3 .3-4.1 1a38 38 0 0 0-27-25.6c-13-3-26.4 2-35 12a40 40 0 0 0-7.6 13.8 7 7 0 0 0-10.8 6l2 30.2c.4 7.3 10.8 8.7 13.3 1.9-6.4-8.7-8.6-22.4-1.5-31.3v-.1c2-12.6 10.8-24 23.2-27.7A31.3 31.3 0 0 1 75 23c3.4 4.5 5.7 9.7 6.7 15.2v.9c7.3 8.7 5 23-1.4 31.5 2.5 6.8 12.8 5.3 13.3-1.9l2-30.1c.2-3.8-2.7-7.1-6.5-7.3" />
  <path  d="M81.5 42.2c-3-5-8.7-7.7-14.5-7.7h-.2c-9.5.7-13 6.2-15.8 12.3l-1 2-.8-2c-2.8-6-7-12.3-16.7-12.3h-.3c-6.3.4-11.8 3.8-14.5 9.7-3 6.5-2 14.4 1 20.8 3.2 6.6 9.1 11.5 14.6 16.2C38.8 86 44.6 90 50.2 94.5c8.7-7.8 18.8-13.9 26.5-22.7 3.6-4 6.1-8.7 7-14.1.8-5.2.6-10.9-2.2-15.5z" /> 
    </g>  
  </mask>
 </defs> 
  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPqVU.jpg" mask="url(#mask)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @bot Пожалуйста. Рад был помочь.